# Is there any way to do a Facebook video chat on Android devices?

Tags: facebook, chat

Is there any way to do a Facebook video chat on Android devices?

Answer (score 0):

Us the messenger app. It now supports HD video calling

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca